# what happens when you call includes on a relation/collection in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a situation where I call includes on a collection and it's exhibiting weird behavior.

In a test, I have this scenario where

```
=> apples
[]


=> apples.rotten
[
    [0] #<Apples:0x007fdff8b49b70> {
                           :id => 1,
                      :user_id => 1,
    }
]
```

and rotten is a scope on apple that uses includes and joins some tables together. The test that I'm running does indeed create an apple associated with the model with the calling methods correctly... but apples is still returning => []

```
=> self.apples
[]

=> self
{
:id => 1
...
}
```

Comment: So... what are you actually asking?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to `#reload apples.rotten`. Oops.